# SQL Server 2012 string functions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a field that can vary in length of the format CxxRyyy where x and y are numeric. I want to choose xx and yyy. For instance, if the field value is C1R12, then I want to get 1 and 12. if I use substring and charindex then I have to use a length, but I would like to use a position like

```
SUBSTRING(WPLocationNew, CHARINDEX('C',WPLocationNew,1)+1,  CHARINDEX('R',WPLocationNew,1)-1)
```

or

```
SUBSTRING(WPLocationNew, CHARINDEX('C',WPLocationNew,1)+1,  LEN(WPLocationNew) - CHARINDEX('R',WPLocationNew,1))
```

to get x, but I know that doesn't work. I feel like there is a fairly simple solution, but I am not coming up with it yet. Any suggestions

Comment: What are the longest strings? Are there other variations involving letters other than C or R? Are they always in that order?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Max length is 5 characters and it is always only 'C' (Column) and 'R' (Row)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these are cell references and will always be in the form `C{1-5 digits}R{1-5 digits}` you can do this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(Original varchar(32));

INSERT @t(Original) VALUES ('C14R4535'),('C1R12'),('C57R123');

;WITH src AS
(
  SELECT Original, c = REPLACE(REPLACE(Original,'C',''),'R','.') 
  FROM @t
)
SELECT Original,  C = PARSENAME(c,2),  R = PARSENAME(c,1) 
FROM src;
```

Output

> | Original | C | R |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | C14R4535 | 14 | 4535 |
> | C1R12 | 1 | 12 |
> | C57R123 | 57 | 123 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=ed341790c685a27e15a05bc54582eeb0)

If you need to protect against other formats, you can add

```
  FROM @t WHERE Original LIKE 'C%[0-9]%R%[0-9]%' 
          AND PATINDEX('%[^C^R^0-9]%', Original) = 0
```

- Updated [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=38028ec62714d3db32207ea997f76226)

Comment: I have never used parse_name before. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are attempting to parse an Excel cell reference. Those are predictably structured or I wouldn't suggest such an embarrassing hack as this.

Basically, take advantage of the fact that a try_cast in SQL ignores spaces when converting strings to numbers.

```
declare @val as varchar(20) = 'C1R12'
declare @newval as varchar(20)
declare @c as smallint
declare @r as smallint

--replace the C with 5 spaces
set @newval = replace(@val,'C','     ')

--replace the R with 5 spaces
set @newval = replace(@newval,'R','     ')

--take a look at the intermediate result, which is '     1     14'
select @newval

set @c = try_cast(left(@newval,11) as smallint)
set @r = try_cast(right(@newval,6) as smallint)

--take a look at the results... two smallint, 1 and 14
select @c, @r
```

That can all be accomplished in one line for each element (a line for column and a line for row) but I wanted you to be able to understand what was happening so this example goes through the steps individually.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of different ways to approach string parsing. Here's just one possible idea:

```
declare @s varchar(10) = 'C01R002';
select
    rtrim( left(replace(stuff(@s, 1, 1, ''), 'R', '          '), 10)) as c,
    ltrim(right(replace(substring(@s, 2, 10), 'R', '          '), 10)) as r
```

Strip out the 'C' and then replace the 'R' with enough spaces so that the left and right sides can be extracted using a fixed length and then easily trimmed back.

`stuff()` and `substring()` as used above are just different ways accomplish exactly the same thing. One advantage here is that it does use fairly portable string functions and it's conceivable that this is somewhat faster. This is also done inline and without multiple steps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's yet another way:

```
declare @val as varchar(20) = 'C12R345'
declare @c   as varchar(5)
declare @r   as varchar(5)

set @c = SUBSTRING(@val, patindex('C%', @val)+1,(patindex('%R%', @val)-1)-patindex('C%', @val) ) 
set @r = SUBSTRING(@val, patindex('%R%', @val)+1, LEN(@val) -patindex('%R%', @val))

select cast(@c as int) as 'C', cast(@r as int) as 'R'
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=68ad9c898bc8ea76ee2175c4b8daa290)